# Infinite Loop and Program Freezing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come across an interesting scenario while working on a Python program that involves generating unique options for a game. In my implementation, I initially used a set to store the options and encountered an issue where the program would freeze, leading to an infinite loop. However, after making a slight modification by switching to a list, the freezing problem disappeared.

I'm curious to understand the underlying reasons behind this behavior and why the second implementation caused the program to freeze. I have my own thoughts on the matter, but I want to gather insights from you all to gain a deeper understanding.

**Prerequisite code**

> ```
> MAX = 20
> MIN = 1
>
> ans = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
> y = random.randint(MIN, ans)
> x = ans - y
> ```

Here are the two implementations:

**Implementation 1 (No freezing issue):**

> ```
> opts = [x]
> while len(opts) < 4:
>
>     opt = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
>
>     if opt not in opts:
>         opts.append(opt)
> ```

**Implementation 2 (Caused program freezing):**

> ```
> opts = {x}
> while len(opts) < 4:
>     opts.add(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
> ```

*Edit*

**Here is the full contents of the function (with implementation 1)**

> def question_generator():
>
> ```
> MAX = 20
> MIN = 1
>
> ans = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
> y = random.randint(MIN, ans)
> x = ans - y
>
> # Generate options list
> opts = [x]
> while len(opts) < 4:
>     opt = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
>     if opt not in opts:
>         opts.append(opt)
>
> random.shuffle(opts)
>
> return (x, y, ans, opts)
> ```

Questions I have about this:

1. What exactly causes the freezing issue in the second implementation?
2. Why does the first implementation resolve the freezing problem?
3. Are there any underlying differences between sets and lists that
   contribute to this behavior?

I really can't seem to understand why there is such a drastic difference, thanks for any insight you may have.

Comment: Please update your question with sample values for `MIN` and `MAX`.

Comment: also, a sample value for `x` would be useful.

Comment: what is your `x` in `opts` though, because in terms of the code you provide, it works fine for me. It stops when `len(opts)=4`.

Comment: Anyway, to see the key difference between sets and lists, do this. `my_set = {1, 2, 3}; my_list = [1, 2, 3]; my_set.add(3); my_list.append(3)`. Then print `my_set` and `my_list`. See the difference?

Comment: Based on the example @slothrop, if the range you set between `MIN` and `MAX` are too close, i think that is the problem.

Comment: @8823 my suspicion too. Like if `MIN = 2, MAX = 3`, the set will never reach 4 members.

Comment: Done now @quamrana

Comment: Your two snippets of code work out to be the same. The only possible reason for a freeze is that `randint()` occasionally may produce awkward values.

Comment: I had been using MIN = 1 and MAX = 20. Sometimes it would freeze and other times it would not using the second implementation. It's just so the case that it hasn't happened at all using the first implementation. I get that you can't append duplicates to sets but I was thinking this would not be an issue because there would be more possible numbers and MIN and MAX were far enough apart.

Comment: I am trying the second snippet and I can't get it to freeze...

Comment: I ran for 15 minutes without a freeze.

Comment: Possibly the rest of the function which is at fault? Which was,

>    random.shuffle(opts)
>    return (x, y, ans, opts)

Comment: print the numbers you want to add to the set

Comment: I've added the rest of the function to the question. I know for sure that the issue was in this as the rest of my program worked.

Comment: If `opts` is a set, then `random.shuffle(opts)` would fail - but it would throw an exception, not just freeze.

Comment: Actually, can you show your full function with implementation 2? (because that would need to be somewhat different from implementation 1, e.g. no shuffle). Like @quamrana, I also haven't been able to make implementation 2 freeze.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when comparing the two data structures, “set” and “list”, one will immediately see significant differences and the best use cases for each.

Honestly looking at your use of both, I don’t think the program should freeze. But nevertheless, I’ll list some of the most common use cases so that you may profile your program and find the real problem.

- Lists are indexed while sets aren’t so sets [do not support indexing or slicing operations.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)
- Although lists and sets are mutable, while elements of lists are mutable, elements of sets are immutable. So an attempt to mutate an element of a set will not work.

Overall the add method of a set is efficient. Set is far faster, in general when testing for membership. In a list, this is O(n), linear in the size of the list. Adding to a set is O(1), independent of the number of the items in the set. [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466278/16770846)

So the best way to tackle this would be profiling your program first to know if that is where the actual problem lies.

Comment: *"So an attempt to mutate an element of a set will not work."* Specifically, mutating an element of a set in a way that changes that element's hash is indeed problematic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953339/what-happens-when-objects-in-a-set-are-altered-to-match-each-other However, Python classes should be designed such that objects never change their hash during their lifetime (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). So when that problem arises, it's arguably a "bad class design" issue rather than a "bad set usage" issue.

Comment: @slothrop thanks for bringing this up and as a matter of fact I did keep this in mind when posting this but I am trying to find every possible reason why the program freezes to begin with.

Comment: More on what @slothrop pointed out. Consider mutation in code only when really necessary. These sources list many valid points on why mutation during a programs lifetime is a bad idea. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30674260/16770846