# user-defined class: hash() and id() and doc

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the doc:

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is their id().

Now from console:

```
class ABC:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

a = ABC()
id(a)
140102888165648
hash(a)
8756430510353
```

Shoudln't `a` have the same hash and id value?

Comment: Which Python version, which platform, and which "bitness" (32/64)?

Comment: I'm using python 3.3.4 version with 64 "bitness"

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11324771/3661996)

Comment: Where in the doc does it say this, if I may ask? I don't see anything about the two being equal.

Comment: here https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-hashable

Comment: @antox: Thanks, I was looking in the wrong place, where the builtins are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

> User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default;
>   with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and
>   `x.__hash__()` returns a result **derived** from `id(x)`.

It seems like the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) is either outdated or inaccurate.

---

The documentation for python3's [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) is slightly different:

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default;
>   with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and
>   `x.__hash__()` returns **an appropriate value** such that `x == y` implies
>   both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

So they even removed the fact that such value should depend on `id`.

Comment: where did you take that definition?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking in the wrong link. However then I don't understand why in the old glossary the wrote good and in the new glossary the changed....

Comment: @antox I have added also the python3 documentation, since it seems like the required semantics changed (it doesn't mention `id` at all).

Comment: @antox Yes, what I'm saying is that the glossary is wrong. It should be updated. They copy-pasted the one for python2.7, when the semantics changed. The real reference is the documentation for `__hash__` which is the one I linked.

Comment: @antox I have just opened [an issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21782) in the python tracker to see if they can fix it.