# Why is a NamedTuple containing mutable objects hashable, when a Tuple containing mutable objects is not?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I understand why a `tuple` which contains a mutable object like `list` is not hashable, since `list` items in the tuple can still be updated.

**example:**

```
# hashable
tuple_test = (1,2,3)
print(tuple_test.__hash__())
```

While this is not hashable:

```
# Not hashable

tuple_test2 = (1,2, [1,2])
print(tuple_test2.__hash__())
```

The above make sense to me.

But when I create a `namedtuple` with `list` items it is still hashable:

```
# hashable
named_tuple = namedtuple("TestTuple", 'name age')
```

and when I add a `list`:

```
# still hashable
named_tuple = namedtuple("TestTuple", ["name", "age"])
print(named_tuple(name="adam", age=20).__hash__())
```

Why this difference between tuples and namedtuples?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324271/what-is-the-default-hash-in-python

Comment: "But when I create a namedtuple with list as items it is still hashable," Where do you do that? You create a named-tuple with a string, `'adam'` and an `int`, `20`...?

Comment: Creating a `namedtuple` *class* via a `list` is not at all the same as creating an *instance* that *contains* a list.

Comment: Write `hash(x)`, not `x.__hash__()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But when I create a namedtuple with list as items it is still
>   hashable...

You never do that. You create a named-tuple with a `str`, `'adam'` and an `int`, `20`

The following:

```
named_tuple = namedtuple("TestTuple", 'name age')
```

And

```
named_tuple = namedtuple("TestTuple", ["name", "age"])
```

Do **not** create `namedtuple` objects, they create `namedtuple` *classes*. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> Returns a new tuple subclass named typename.

In other words, `collections.namedtuple` is a factory function that returns a *class*. If you create instances of those classes, their instances follow the same rules as regular `tuple` instances.

So consider:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> TestTuple = namedtuple('TestTuple', ['name', 'age'])
>>> type(TestTuple)
<class 'type'>
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> type(A)
<class 'type'>
```

TestTuple, the return value of the `namedtuple` factory function, *is not a namedtuple instance*, it is an instance of `type`, like all other classes.

When you create instances of this class:

```
>>> test_tuple = TestTuple('adam',32)
>>> type(test_tuple)
<class '__main__.TestTuple'>
```

They follow the usual rules of hashability that regular `tuple` objects do:

```
>>> hash(test_tuple)
5589201399616687819
>>> test_tuple = TestTuple('adam', [32, 31])
>>> hash(test_tuple)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Note, the fieldnames argument accepts either a sequence (e.g. a list) of fieldnames, or for convenience, a space/comma-delimited string of fieldnames, so also from the docs:

> ...
>   The field_names are a sequence of strings such as ['x', 'y'].
>   Alternatively, field_names can be a single string with each fieldname
>   separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'.