# Python: How to find the intersection between two lists based on object's id?

Tags: python

I know if I had two lists of, say integers, I could simply do `list(set(list1) & set(list2))` to get the intersection. However, in my two lists, I have mutable objects, namely `Node`s. Node is a class that can be initialized with a value.

Without having to do a double for-loop, is there any way to get the intersection of two lists based on their ids? I'm looking for something similar to `list(set(list1) & set(list2))`.

**Update**: By id I am referring to the built-in `id()` function in Python which returns the address of where the object is stored in memory.

So, I'm asking what is the Intersection of say, `[Node1, Node2, Node3]` and `[Node100, Node2, Node3]`. Obviously I can't use the set intersection method above. I need to identify they are the same by accessing memory. If I can't try to identify them based on their value attribute because they may Node1 may have the same value as Node100, but they are not the same objects in memory.

Comment: What do you mean "based on their ids"? Is the id an attribute of `Node` object?

Comment: By 'id' do you mean references to the same objects which may appear in both `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: @Primusa. Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Philip has a much better answer. there's no point for me to keep mine up; I upvote his answer and move on.

Comment: To be sure as is not clear to me: do you want to keep in your final list two Nodes with the same value if they are not the same object in memory or not?

Comment: What you suggested works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to intersect two sets. In this case you can just check if the `id()` exists in another set.

```
set2 = {id(n) for n in list2}
result = [n for n in list1 if id(n) in set2]
```

The complexity of this code is `O(n1 + n2)`. I'll explain this in following equivalent but more readable code:

```
set2 = {id(n) for n in list2}  # O(n2)
result = []
for n in list1:  # O(n1)
    if id(n) in set2:  # O(1)
        result.append(n)  # O(1)
```

In total it's `O(n1 + n2)`.

---

There is also an alternative solution if you can make change to the `Node` class by just defining the [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method.

```
class Node:
    ...

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)

    def __eq__(self, another):
        return id(self) == id(another)


list1 = [...]
list2 = [...]

result = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Comment: I mean the python `id` built-in function, not my attribute

Comment: Also, this is just a for loop

Comment: @MadPhysicist well you have to convert list to set first. Internally the `set()` initializer will also walk through the whole list (and I think it counts a loop).

Comment: @AlanH. This is not just a for loop. The set construction is O(n2), and the loop is O(n1). This makes it O(n1+n2), not O(n1*n2). For comparable list sizes, you end up with O(n) instead of O(n^2). And you can trivially replace n.id with id(n)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you explain more as to why it's O(list1 + list2)? If I have a for loop, and for each iteration, I have to create a set of `k` elements, isn't that just multiplying the run-times?

Comment: @Philip. `return hash(id(self))`? Or is the hash of an integer just itself?

Comment: @MadPhysicist actually by default `__hash__` returns what `id() / 16` returns... (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324771/2644759)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggested will work.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node {}".format(self.value)

nodes1 = [Node(1), Node(2), Node(3)]
nodes2 = nodes1[:2] + [Node(4)]

common_nodes = set(nodes1) & set(nodes2)

print(common_nodes) # {Node 2, Node 1}
```

The reason this works is because despite being mutable, an instance of a class for which you did not define `__hash__` or `__eq__` will be hashed and compared by its `id` by default because it inherits those methods from `object`.

You can check this is true with the following experiment.

```
>>> obj = object()
>>> hash(obj)
155115580943
>>> id(obj)
2481849295088
>>> id(obj) // 16 == hash(obj)
True
```