# Hash method is defaulted in python 2, not python 3

Tags: python, hash

I've come across an example of weird behavior when transitioning some code from python 2 to python 3. Below's a minimal (?) example of it:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x

b = Bar(1)
print(hash(b))
```

when run with `python2`, this code produces some output (a hash of `Bar(1)`), while `python3` causes a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Bar'`

this means that `__hash__` is somehow inherited (from `object` ?) in python 2.

So, my questions are: what is the hash of `Bar(1)` in python 2? And why is the behaviour different?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the data model has changed. [In Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by
>   default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with
>   themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that
>   `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.
>
> **A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to `None`**. When the
>   `__hash__()` method of a class is `None`, instances of the class will raise an appropriate TypeError when a program attempts to retrieve
>   their hash value, and will also be correctly identified as unhashable
>   when checking `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Hashable)`.

So, since you've defined a `__eq__` explicitely, but did not define a `__hash__`, Python 3 objects will implicitely have `__hash__ = None`, causing the objects to be unhashable

In [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by
>   default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with
>   themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns a result derived from `id(x)`.

So it is hashing based on identity, which is a problem, because it isn't consistent with your `__eq__`. This is a reason that Python 3 switched behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

From [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

> A class that overrides **eq**() and does not define **hash**() will
>   have its **hash**() implicitly set to None. When the **hash**() method
>   of a class is None, instances of the class will raise an appropriate
>   TypeError when a program attempts to retrieve their hash value, and
>   will also be correctly identified as unhashable when checking
>   isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Hashable).

See [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for the Python 2 version.

Comment: The second link only says "x.__hash__() returns a result derived from id(x).". How do I see what how the result is derived?

Comment: You can see some discussions of that regarding different versions of Python in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324271/what-is-the-default-hash-in-python/11324771