# How to tell if an object/instance is hashable

Tags: python, hash

I found an interesting observation lately, that there are things to impact the hashability of an object/instance of a class. And I am wondering how and why?

For example, I got a linked list class called `ListNode`:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

   def __repr__(self):
        if self.next:
            return "{}->{}".format(self.val, repr(self.next))
        else:
            return "{}".format(self.val)

    # def __eq__(self, other):
        # if not self and not other:
        #     return True
        # elif not self or not other:
        #     return False
        # else:
        #     return self.val == other.val and self.next == other.next

     # def __eq__(self, other):
        # return str(self) == str(other)
```

Notice that I blocked the `__eq__` method.
Now if I create an instance:

```
A = ListNode(1)
B = ListNode(2)
C = ListNode(3)
A.next = B
B.next = C
print(hash(A))
```

Then it is hashable, however, I do get different output number everytime I run it.

Now if I unblock the `__eq__` method, all of sudden it is not hashable anymore. Why?

It seems that the `hash` method will use `__eq__`. And how does it know it is not hashable after `__eq__` is enabled?

**Additional:
If I write the `__eq__`  method to just compare the `str` version of the two linked list (the second `__eq__` method), I thought this could solve the problem, because by converting the linked list into a `string`, it becomes an hashable data, but I still get the `unhashable` error message**

Thanks!

> **According to @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment:**

`__eq__` will remove the default `__hash__` method, making it unhashable.
So I added my own`__hash__` mehtod:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(id(self))
```

This solved the problem and made `ListNode` hashable again with `__eq__` enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753498/hash-method-is-defaulted-in-python-2-not-python-3/55753619#55753619

Comment: In any case, because if you define an `__eq__`, you must define a compatible `__hash__`. If you don't define an `__eq__`, user-defined types hash based on identity by default

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, in logic it make sense. And it actually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a class does not define an __eq__() method it should not define a __hash__() operation either; if it defines __eq__() but not __hash__(), its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections.
>
> (...)
>
> A class that overrides __eq__() and does not define __hash__() will have its __hash__() implicitly set to None. When the __hash__() method of a class is None, instances of the class will raise an appropriate TypeError when a program attempts to retrieve their hash value, and will also be correctly identified as unhashable when checking isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Hashable). [1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

The introduction of the __eq__() method hence sets the __hash__() to None. You could add a custom hash, to allow for the construction above:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return self.val
```

More information you can find here: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Comment: Ok, maybe I can create my own hash method, but this still does not explain why and how `__eq__` can impact the hashability.

Comment: Hashable does not mean immutable. You can define a valid hash function for a mutable object as long as you don't take any of the mutable parts into consideration.

Comment: **[Hashable absolutely *does* mean immutable](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2019/02/01/hashable-objects-must-be-immutable).** Yes, third-party developers technically *can* violate this semantic constraint – but doing so renders the resulting types non-deterministically insane and unusable in most common hashable contexts (e.g., `dict` keys, `set` items), which is bad. Ergo, nobody in the history of Python would ever do or has ever done this. Ergo, hashable == immutable.