# object ID vs hash vs class object id

Tags: python, hash, objectid

I got confused between these three types of IDs, why python have 3 different id types? and what is the use of them?

class Person:

def **init**(self, name):

```
self.name=name
```

p1=Person("Allen")

print(p1)

print(id(p1))

print(hash(p1))

output:

<**main**.Person object at 0x000001AE10CC7FD0>

1847117774800

115444860925

Comment: reformat your post so that every bit of code is in a code block

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324771/14909621). Also note that `0x000001AE10CC7FD0 == 1847117774800`